# Unfocus an action button after a click (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

This is a bit minor, but after clicking an action button (normally light gray) in a Shiny app, it turns a darker gray and the focus remains on it. The user has to click somewhere else for the action button to return to its normal lighter color.

Try it out here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/actionbutton-demo.html

The lack of automatically reverting to a lighter color means the user doesn't get a visual feedback that the button was successfully pressed.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: When I click the *GO* buttion, it returns to a light-grey colour

Comment: Oh... maybe this is OS dependent. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I tried in Chromium, Firefox, and Opera. The button remains dark and has the dotted "focus" outline in all of them.

Comment: On Mac and Ubuntu 16.04 it removes the focus for me (R 3.3.1, shiny 0.13.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by disabling the button while the process is running, it will also prevent people from re-clicking it while you are waiting on the result. Have a look at `shinyjs` package which has a lot of nice features. Note that I added 2 second delay to mimic long operation.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
    tags$div(style="display:inline-block",title="Push Me",bsButton("goButton", label = "Button", block = TRUE,style="primary"))
  ),
  mainPanel(useShinyjs(),verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    shinyjs::disable("goButton")
    Sys.sleep(2)
    shinyjs::enable("goButton")
    input$n
    })

  output$nText <- renderText({ntext()})

})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Disabled Button**
[image]

**Enabled Button**
[image]

Comment: This works even better. I actually clicked an input twice during long (network) operations behind an "actionbutton." Great solution! Is there also a progress animation to go with it?

Comment: Note to self: don't forget the `useShinyjs()` call in the ui.

Comment: I don't want to clutter this with other requests as users might be confused by the header, but you can add the progress by doing: `output$nText <- renderText({withProgress(message = 'Computation is in progress...', value = 0,ntext())})` If you want prettier progress bar look [here](https://jackolney.github.io/2016/shiny/)

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the webbrowser to unfocus the actionbutton, when it is clicked. This way, you don't get the effects you describe. Below is a (more or less) two line JavaScript call to achieve this. The script reads very straightforward. When the document is ready, we add a functionality, that if a button is clicked, then it is `blurred` immediately (looses focus).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$script(HTML("
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn').on('click', function(){$(this).blur()});
      })
    ")),
    numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
    br(),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # builds a reactive expression that only invalidates 
  # when the value of input$goButton becomes out of date 
  # (i.e., when the button is pressed)
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$n
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```